# Error in Dijkstra algorithm in android

Tags: android, algorithm, dijkstra

I am implementing the 'Dijkstra algorithm' in Android for making an app for Metro Network.
When I click on the button to show the path, it stops the app.
I have explicitly defined the graph to store in array adj[][].

MetroRoute class

```
public class MetroRoute extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText source, destination;
TextView Route;
Button button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.metroroute);
    source = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSource);
    destination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDest);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bGetroute);
    Route = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRoute);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int count, i;
    count = findpath(Integer.parseInt(source.getText().toString()), Integer.parseInt(destination.getText().toString()), path, sdist );
    if(sdist!=0)
      {
       Route.setText("Shortest distance is : \n" + sdist);
       Route.setText("Shortest Path is : ");
       for( i=count;i>1;i--)
         Route.setText(path[i] + " -> ");
       Route.setText(path[i]);
      }

      else
       Route.setText("There is no path from source to destination node\n");
 }

int adj[][] = {{3,2,3,0,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5},{1,2,3,4,5}}; 
int MAX = 10, TEMP = 0, PERM =1, INFINITY = 9999, path[], sdist=0, n=5 ;

private class Node {
    int predecessor[];
    int dist[];            /*minimum distance of node from source*/
    int status[];
}

int findpath(int s,int d,int path[],int sdist)
{
 Node state = new Node();
 int i, min=0, count=0, current, newdist, u, v ;
 sdist=0;

 /* Make all nodes temporary */

 for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
 {
  state.predecessor[i]=0;
  state.dist[i] = INFINITY;
  state.status[i] = TEMP;
 }

 /*Source node should be permanent*/

 state.predecessor[s]=0;
 state.dist[s] = 0;
 state.status[s] = PERM;

 /*Starting from source node until destination is found*/

 current=s;

 while(current!=d)
 {
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
   /*Checks for adjacent temporary nodes */
   if ( adj[current][i] > 0 && state.status[i] == TEMP )
   {
    newdist=state.dist[current] + adj[current][i];
    /*Checks for Relabeling*/
    if( newdist < state.dist[i] )
     {
      state.predecessor[i] = current;
      state.dist[i] = newdist;
     }
    }
   }

   /*Search for temporary node with minimum distance make it current node*/

   min=INFINITY;
   current=0;

   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
   {
    if(state.status[i] == TEMP && state.dist[i] < min)  
    {
     min = state.dist[i];
     current=i;
    }
   }

   if(current==0)                       /*If Source or Sink node is isolated*/
    return 0;
   state.status[current]=PERM;
  }

 /* Getting full path in array from destination to source   */

 while( current!=0 )
 {
  count++;
  path[count]=current;
  current=state.predecessor[current];
 }

 /*Getting distance from source to destination*/

 for(i=count;i>1;i--)
 {
  u=path[i];
  v=path[i-1];
  sdist+= adj[u][v];
 }

 return (count) ;
 }

}
```

Comment: `it stops the app`???

Comment: I don't understand why you've implemented Dijkstra's algorithm in this way. Try following the [pseudocode on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Pseudocode).

Comment: Same question as @JordiVermeulen, I don't even recognize the algorithm !

Comment: I saw this pseudocode earlier but couldn't understand, so i tried it myself and took help from some website where it was implemented in C language.

Comment: Dijkstra is realy hard to understand, but any modification usually breaks the code. Just copy it 1:1 from a reliable source. Avoid any modifications. Further  there are optimized variants, like Dijkstra with Fibanacci Heap, which are even more difficult to understand. Don't try to self invent the shortes path algorithm. Some professional SW engineers I know who had to modify the dijkstra failed in doing it correctly. That was detected some years later, when the code failed only in special situations.

Comment: Thanks @AlexWien I will try to get some more reliable source.

Comment: You mention in a comment it might be at the `findpath` call. Possible reasons: `source`,`source.getText()`, `destination`, or `destination.getText()` could be null. Your `Integer.parseInt(...)` may not be getting a numeric value. I don't see where `path` is getting initialized to a size. So uses like `path[count]=current;` could be throwing. Checking those might set you in the correct direction.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to find the problem is to use the console of the adk to see the exceptions thrown by the device. When you start your app from your IDE (Eclipse, Android Studio) in a virtual device, or even your smartphone, you will get logcat-messages, which will contain the exceptions like for example the NullPointerException. You will then find the lines where the exception is thrown and then you can do some further testing (like writing some values to the console (System.Out.println(...) or System.err.println(...)).

You can post your log so we can take a look at it.

You may want to use my Dijkstra-implementation, too:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> dijkstra(Graph graph, Integer orig,
        Integer dest, TreeMap<Integer, Integer> distance,
        ArrayList<Integer> nodesLeft) throws Exception 
{
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = graph.getNodes().iterator();
    Integer next;


    TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> paths = new TreeMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();


    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        next = iterator.next();

        distance.put(next, -1);

        paths.put(next, new ArrayList<Integer>());

    }
    distance.put(orig, 0);
    nodesLeft.addAll(Collections.unmodifiableCollection(graph.getNodes()));

    while (!nodesLeft.isEmpty()) {
        int u = nodesLeft.get(0);

        Collection<Integer> edgesOfU = graph.getEdges(u);
        Iterator<Integer> itEdgesOfU = edgesOfU.iterator();
        int nextEdge;
        while (itEdgesOfU.hasNext()) {
            nextEdge = itEdgesOfU.next();
            if (nodesLeft.contains(nextEdge)) {


                int distU = distance.get(u);
                if ((distance.get(nextEdge) == -1)
                        || (distU + 1) < distance.get(nextEdge)) {
                    distance.put(nextEdge, distU + 1);


                    ArrayList<Integer> tmpList = paths.get(nextEdge);


                    for (int a : paths.get(u)) {
                        tmpList.add(a);
                    }

                    tmpList.add(nextEdge);
                }
            }
        }
        nodesLeft.remove(0);
    }
    return paths.get(dest);
}
```

I used some self-defined Graphs with the following Interface:

```
import java.util.Collection;

public interface Graph {


    public Integer addNode();


    public void removeNode(Integer id) throws Exception,
        UnsupportedOperationException;


    public Collection<Integer> getNodes();


    public boolean addEdge(Integer orig, Integer dest) throws Exception;


    public boolean removeEdge(Integer orig, Integer dest) throws Exception,
        UnsupportedOperationException;

    public Collection<Integer> getEdges(Integer orig) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: I know you can't comment due to the lack of rep, but please try to be a little more thorough next time

Comment: Yes, do you test your App directly with your IDE? In Eclipse you will get logs to your console directly on excecution and you will see the thrown Exceptions like "NullPointerException" and the line in which it is thrown.

Comment: yes I implement from IDE, I see many errors including nullpointerexception. Most of the errors are in the line where I have called findpath() in OnClick method.

Comment: can you post the whole Log with all exceptions? In most cases you can find the line where the error is occuring and then you can add some outputs to console just to see which data you have there.

Comment: All are in the line where findpath() is called. I think either it is related to that line of call or the method definition.

Comment: Of course, but it should be something in that method, so the log will tell the exact line i think.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Rerito : you are right, thanks for taking my reputation into account ;-) - I tried to describe it a bit better.

Comment: @ianolito : It's not the final answer, I know, but it might be a way to find it. If my reputation would be better, I would have written a comment.